# using redis and ruby to implement a tiny short url app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, redis, runtime-error

I'm making a short URL app, using Ruby, Sinatra, and Redis. Currently it's under 15 lines:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'redis'
require 'uri'

configure do
  REDISTOGO_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/"
  uri = URI.parse(REDISTOGO_URL)
  REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

post '/shorten' do
  a = rand(9999)
  REDIS.set(a.to_s, params[:long])
  "<pre>http://199.19.118.186/get/#{a}</pre>"
  #haml :shorten                                                                    
end

get '/get/:url' do
  redirect REDIS.get(params[:url])
end
```

Where `index.haml` is a form that `POST`s `long` to `/shorten`. I've no problem with that.

Right now, however, when I try to use Redis (with the server running, yes), I get this error:
[image: RuntimeError]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Copy/paste from Emacs... *facepalm*

EDIT: When trying to access redis alone from ruby (code below), I get this:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:47:in `call': ERR unknown command (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:841:in `set'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:840:in `set'
    from test_redis.rb:9
```

With this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'redis'
require 'uri'

REDISTOGO_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/"
uri = URI.parse(REDISTOGO_URL)
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)

REDIS.set("test", "blah")
puts REDIS.get("test")
```

Comment: I suggest you should also use sets for url minification. sismember is powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby being case sensitive, I would try to replace REDIS.SET by REDIS.set and REDIS.GET by REDIS.get. You can find the documentation of the Redis client here:

https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb

I have tested your example with ruby 1.8.7. (default on my Linux box).
After installing sinatra, haml, redis and hiredis gems, I have modified the code as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'redis'
require 'uri'

configure do
  REDISTOGO_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/"
  uri = URI.parse(REDISTOGO_URL)
  REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end

get '/' do
  "Hello"
  haml :index
end

post '/shorten' do
  a = rand(9999)
  REDIS.set(a.to_s, "http://"+params[:long])
  "<pre>http://localhost:4567/get/#{a}</pre>"
end

get '/get/:url' do
  redirect REDIS.get(params[:url])
end
```

I have added the following template in views/index.haml.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title My Sinatra Website
  %body
    %h1 Welcome
    %p
      Welcome to my website made with Sinatra and HAML
    %form{ :action => "/shorten", :method=>"POST" }
      %fieldset
        %input{ :type =>"text", :name=>"long" }
        %input{ :type =>"submit" }
```

Once Redis is started on port 6379 and sinatra on port 4567, it works like a charm.
I suggest you check your ruby installation and try to access Redis from ruby with a simple non sinatra script.

**UPDATE:**

The error message is peculiar because normally, when an unknown command is sent to the server, the faulty command is provided:

```
ERR unknown command 'dummy'
```

while you just have:

```
ERR unknown command
```

Actually, this specific fix was introduced in Redis server more than 2 years ago (in December 2009) - an eternity for Redis.

https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/2c14807b2dd5c15f1471bec32a7c6dbb077720ee

In other words, you are trying to use a very old (i.e. pre 1-3) version of Redis server with the last version of the Redis client ruby gem, which probably does not support anymore the initial protocol. You may want to compile and install a recent version of Redis server (it is easy), it should work better.

Comment: Thanks... building and installing. Will see what happens next.

Comment: `redis-cli 2.4.8` and for some reason I get the exact same error. No change.

Comment: redis-cli is irrelevant. If you have these specific error messages, the version of the *server* is wrong. What does the INFO command return?

Comment: Once you have compiled Redis, go to directory src in the Redis source distribution, and type ./redis-cli info

Comment: Okay, now the only issue is that the redirect doesn't work... I just get a 404 when using `/get/num` :(